# Comma separated words Regex (html input pattern)

Tags: html, regex, validation, input

im trying to force the user to input comma seperated words and reject any white space seperated words using the `pattern` attribute thats part of the HTML5 `<input/>` tag .

My following Expression expression doesn't work even though [this](https://www.regextester.com/97107) says it does when I plug it in and test it.

My expression : `^((([a-zA-Z]\s*)+)\, ?(([a-zA-Z]\s*)+))$`

```
<div class="col-md-6">

    <input type="text" id="traits" name = "traits" class="form-control"  placeholder = "crazy, hyper, outgoing" pattern="^((([a-zA-Z]\s*)+)\, ?(([a-zA-Z]\s*)+))$" required>

</div>
```

Comment: This one? `^[a-zA-Z]+(,[a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Comment: @kishkin Thank you sir, it works perfectly. im assuming that the regex I get from that website won't work on input tags? post as answer for upvote

Comment: This one `^(([1-9]\d{9})\,([1-9]\d{9}))$` could be modified a bit: `^[1-9]\d{9}(,[1-9]\d{9})*$`. It will allow numbers starting with a non zero digit, numbers should be exactly 10 digits long, same about the comma: no spaces allowed, no more than one comma at a time, and commas should be only between numbers.

Comment: @kishkin I was trying to accept words only. either one separate word like "crazy" or a list of words like "crazy,hyper,fast" or even with spaces between the commas as such "crazy , hyper ,  fast"

Comment: Then a little fix for the spaces `^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This allows only comma separated words:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(,[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

No spaces allowed, no more than one comma at a time, and commas should be only between words.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vejDb7/1)